# Duplicating layers in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis

I'm having trouble with duplicating vector layers in QGIS 3.4. Each time I try and duplicate a layer, the layers do not act independently of one another and if I make changes to one layer, the changes also apply to the copy/original layer. How do you duplicate layers so they act independently? Do you instead need to select features and create a new shapefile layer? This seems odd as there are instructions in QGIS 3.4 for duplicating layers which act independently! I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: ah ok I see! thank you :-). ive created a new shapefile layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS' *Duplicate layer* feature will create another instance of the **same base data** that acts independently **in terms of styling**! Changes to the base data (the shapefile) will be present **in all instances of that data**.

If you want to duplicate the base data, either save as file, or duplicate the file in your OS and load separately.

Alternatively, you can work with the *DB Manager* / *Virtual Layers* to create in-memory layer from your data that act as (temporary) independent data sources.