# Duplicate layer in QGIS (change data in base-layer does not change data in copy?)

Tags: qgis, layers, duplication

I was wondering for a time what `Duplicate` a layer in QGIS actually does. Reading this question: [Duplicating layers in QGIS 3.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346184/duplicating-layers-in-qgis-3-4)
I was assuming that when duplicating a layer I could style each individually, however if:

"Changes to the base data (the shapefile) will be present in all instances of that data."

Yet I do not see this behaviour. I created a simple polygon, saved it, duplicated it. I then changed the original polygon layer. While the baselayer obviously chaged, the duplicated layer did not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably you're missing something, yes.

Comment: The way your question is phrased made unclear what you mean when you said "I then changed the original polygon layer" Did you mean you changed the symbology (as the beginning of your question seem to imply) or did you mean you updated the data (attribute or geometry) ? If you updated the data what did you change ?

Comment: Thank you all! I think I simply missed something. There is even a big banner stating that it is using the same datasource when duplicating... 
Sorry about that. I'll delete the question

Comment: I agree with you @Lenn. When I add new fields to the base layer, even after refreshing, the duplicated layers do not update with the new fields.

Answer (score 4):

You won't see any change in the duplicated layer until you pan or zoom.  Another reason you may not be seeing the new features, is that the symbology of the duplicated layer does not include a symbol for the data in the new feature.